# Execute function on dropdown menu change in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, function

Here is a little code snippet that works somewhat well but not quite what I am trying to achieve:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method='post'>
    Display
    <select name="displayOptions" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option selected value="all">all</option>
        <option value="open">open</option>
        <option value="reserved">reserved</option>
        <option value="blocked">blocked</option>
    </select> computers
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["displayOptions"])){
        if ($_POST["displayOptions"]=='all')
           allFunction();
        if ($_POST["displayOptions"]=='open')
           openFunction();
        etc...
   }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

As soon as the user chooses a dropdown selection I want the action to take place. I also want the default action to be "all" and for that to happen as soon as the form is loaded. The code snippet above works well with the exception of 2 things.

1. 'all' is selected by default (Working As Intended), however allFunction() doesn't run. Even if you select another option and then select 'all' again, 'all' still doesn't work. I would like the allFunction to run as soon as this form loads up with 'all' selected and, of course, to be able to choose 'all' again later.
2. Whenever a different selection is selected, it loads the correct function (WAI), however the dropdown turns back to all. I know why it does this (becuase the page is being reloaded and 'all' is the default selected value), but I'd like it to stay on the selected option!

As I typed this out I have a feeling I can tackle #2 with a $_SESSION variable but I am still stumped why the first option in the select dropdown is not registering.

Comment: You'd probably benefit more by using ajax. Look for that and samples from tutorials. There's a lot of stuff out there, believe me. I wouldn't steer you wrong.

Comment: If this really stems from possible errors, check your console and enable error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Funk, you may want to look into ajax calls instead to avoid reloading the page when selecting something (which is arguably a poor user experience), but if you insist on using the same structure, you may do this:

```
<?php
    // Set the option selected ("all" by default)
    $option_selected = !empty($_POST["displayOptions"])? $_POST["displayOptions"] : "all";
?>
```

...

```
<select name="displayOptions" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="all" <?php if ($option_selected == "all") echo "selected" ?>>all</option>
    <option value="open" <?php if ($option_selected == "open") echo "selected" ?>>open</option>
    <option value="reserved" <?php if ($option_selected == "reserved") echo "selected" ?>>reserved</option>
    <option value="blocked" <?php if ($option_selected == "blocked") echo "selected" ?>>blocked</option>
</select>
```

...

```
<?php
    if ($option_selected == "all")
       allFunction();
    else if ($option_selected == "open")
       openFunction();
    etc...
?>
```

I haven't tested it but it should work fine.

Comment: This works beautifully! I am new to PHP and I was doing EVERYTHING with forms and if(isset ($_POST) blocks. I didn't realize you could do it this way. A huge epiphany just occurred in my brain,  thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Remember that you can do plenty on the client side with simple JS. For instance, if your functions above only display HTML with little logic, you can load all elements at once and hide them with `display:none`, and when your user selects something, show the appropriate element(s) with `display:block` to avoid reloading the whole page

Comment: Trying to implement this into my project and its not working as I expected :( Let me try to illustrate my flow: after login page, users click login, it checks db to make sure username is valid, stores username in a SESSION var, then start() function gets called. My login page still displays at the top, this is how i wanted it. Within the start function, i display some 'start text', and this darn dropdown menu. The default 'all' selection is WAI and runs my allFunction (which displays more text underneath the dropdown). When i select 'open', the form disappears along with all my 'start text'

Comment: All I want this dropdown to do is display something different underneath depending on what is selected, but this seems to have reloaded my whole page without my start() func (which is where this dropdown lives)

Comment: As long as you keep `onchange="this.form.submit()"` the page will reload on user selection.

Comment: This seems to be what you're trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/fc8kzb02/
Change the name of classes as you see fit, but you get the logic...

Comment: Is it possible to do this without divs and in PHP? Uhhhg I was so confident last night.

Comment: PHP ==> server side
JS ==> client side

Comment: I understand that but my whole website is PHP and it works fine. I dont want to start inserting JS in random places. I know I can get this to work in PHP, im just doing something wrong. Thanks for trying tho...i'll get back to here if I finally figure it out

Comment: You won't be able to run PHP without a server request. Showing/hiding HTML elements should be done with JS. If computation or heavy database requests are needed, reload (or send to different page), or use ajax calls (HTTP request without reloading the page). You should first define what you want to do and the user experience you want to provide. Each HTTP request has a cost (waiting time, page reload, etc.) but you dont want to load and hide too much data at first page load if it may not be used.

Comment: In the rest of my website, i just load new forms+text and tables on button clicks. I want to do the same thing here but with this dropdown. It shouldn't be too hard, im just doing something wrong

Comment: PHP and JS co-exist by design. You shouldn't be reluctant to use JS as it's a great tool to manipulate HTML elements without reloading the page. And it shouldn't be placed in random places. If it's just a few lines, put it at the end of your script, after your HTML.

Comment: Ok, I tried it your way with JS inserts, If you are still willing to help me, copy paste whatever you see in https://jsfiddle.net/k8zsaboq/ over to phpfiddle.org to run. Sorry this is taking so long

Comment: Oops, and you can remove the php tags within the select form, that was from a previous test

Comment: never mind, those php tags were within the JS, leave them there.

Comment: I'm so close! https://jsfiddle.net/56capuLd/ (need copy past into phpfiddle.org)

Comment: I see why you didn't want to add JS now. You need to structure and order your code. It'll be useful for readibility and future maintenance. Also, you may not place a form inside another. From what I see, you don't even need PHP here. This is what you should be aiming for: https://jsfiddle.net/La0hwkj6/ (just add the URL you want the form to be submitted to in the action attribute)

Comment: my showFucntions display database tables. I figured it out thought, I cant concatenate <div>function</div> in a single echo using dot notation. It echos the functions first and then does the divs. Call stack ordering i guess...it works when i echo out a div, then call my function, then echo out closing divs. Its messy but it works! Thanks for your patience lol

Comment: Good. You should still consider sticking to a maintainable structure like so: https://jsfiddle.net/mn9c3zqx/